# Why do positive densities exist on any smooth manifold?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, differential-forms

(All manifolds are smooth)

I am studying Density on a smooth manifold which is a smooth section of the Density bundle. An excercise asks

> Using the fact that positive densities form an open set of Density bundle and that on each vector space positive densities form a convex set, show that any smooth manifold has a positive density.

My question is this

> Why can't the solution of the above problem be used to say any smooth manifold has a positive top form? (I know it's false because there are non orientable manifolds)

Also, how does one show the existence of positive density anyway?

Comment: Can you show they exist locally (i.e. on a coordinate patch)?

Comment: Yes. Taking the absolute value of the standard n-form on each Euclidean neighborhood.

Comment: Once you have that, it's just a matter of stitching those local densities together into a global one. Partitions of unity are useful for that kind of thing.

Comment: What's the failure for positive n-forms?

Comment: Where did you use convexity in your argument? Note that there is no such thing as a "positive" $n$-form.

Comment: Okay I understand now. When $h_i$ is a partition of unity, the sum over $h_i$.$d_i$ where d are the local densities, that sum is still postive because of convexity.